# Array Formula (return number of leave days taken if dates across multiple months) not working properly

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have an array formula that's not working exactly as I want.

The formula I have does not return correct value (returns FALSE) when leave dates are in the same month and month = current month

The formula is supposed to check for these conditions:

- Col. E = Annual Leave
- Col. J = Complete

and return the number of leave days taken by an employee for each month as per these conditions:
(let's assume Current month = Feb-2019)

a) IF Col. O = Yes AND Current month = Leave end date (means start date and end date are in the same month = current month) 
 THEN return number of leave days taken

b) IF Col. P = Yes (leave dates start in one month and end in another month)

(i) IF Current month = Leave start date THEN return number of days between leave start date and end of start date month

(ii) IF Current month = Leave end date THEN return total days taken (Col. H) minus number of days between leave start date and end of start date month

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if(($J$2:$J<>"Complete")*($E$2:$E<>"Annual Leave"),"",if($P$2:$P="yes",if(month($F$2:$F)=month(R$1),NETWORKDAYS.INTL($F$2:$F,EOMONTH($F$2:$F,0),1,Holidays!$B$2:$B),if(month($G$2:$G)=month(R$1),$H$2:$H-NETWORKDAYS.INTL($F$2:$F,EOMONTH($F$2:$F,0),1,Holidays!$B$2:$B),if(month($G$2:$G)=month(R$1),if($O$2:$O="Yes",$H$2:$H,0)))))),"x"))
```

The formula I have does not return correct value (returns FALSE) when leave dates are in the same month and month = current month

All other conditions are OK (i.e. if True, all other conditions are executed properly and correct value displayed except the above condition)

Link to [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZisqfI3ni5SkYi6oVgiMeLvEx6SRrUM1-jWDJvr_w7A/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: screenshot of datasheet with the array formula]

Comment: For clarification, the Google sheet is a live sheet linked to a Google Form. The formula needs to update itself whenever a new response is received

Comment: Added link to Google Sheet

Comment: @player0   No, what I needed was to make the formula work properly...

Answer (score 1):

I've done some more research - and also based on the suggestion - I have managed to resolve this problem.

Here's the working formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(if((($J$2:$J="Complete")*($E$2:$E="Annual Leave")),
IF($P$2:$P="Yes",
IF(month($F$2:$F)=month(R$1),NETWORKDAYS.INTL($F$2:$F,EOMONTH($F$2:$F,0),1,Holidays!$B$2:$B),
IF(month($G$2:$G)=month(R$1),$H$2:$H-NETWORKDAYS.INTL($F$2:$F,EOMONTH($F$2:$F,0),1,Holidays!$B$2:$B),
IF(month($G$2:$G)=month(R$1)))),
IF((($O$2:$O="Yes")*(month($F$2:$F)=month(R$1))),$H$2:$H,"")),""),""))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 3 incomplete IFs which return falses...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(
 IF(($J$2:$J="Complete")*($E$2:$E="Annual Leave"),
 IF($P$2:$P="yes",
 IF(MONTH($F$2:$F)=MONTH(S$1), NETWORKDAYS.INTL($F$2:$F, EOMONTH($F$2:$F, 0), 1, Holidays!$B$2:$B),
 IF(MONTH($G$2:$G)=MONTH(S$1), $H$2:$H-NETWORKDAYS.INTL($F$2:$F, EOMONTH($F$2:$F, 0), 1, Holidays!$B$2:$B),
 IF(MONTH($G$2:$G)=MONTH(S$1),
 IF($O$2:$O="Yes", $H$2:$H, 0), ))), ), ), ))
```

[image: 0]